# Zooming on a HTML <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I'm creating a webpage that draws a trail along a path as the page is scrolled, using canvas to draw the trail and SVGs to determine the path coordinates. (Similar to this demo - https://tympanus.net/Development/StorytellingMap/)

I have a hidden canvas set up as a 'room' which contains the full map background, then draws from this to the main canvas (using a 'camera' to get the position). I've managed to get the background to zoom using drawImage to scale the selected area as follows:

```
ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    camera.position.x + ((canvas.width  - (canvas.width  / zoom)) / 2),
    camera.position.y + ((canvas.height - (canvas.height / zoom)) / 2),
    canvas.width / zoom,
    canvas.height / zoom,
    0,
    0,
    canvas.width,
    canvas.height
);
```

The line is drawn by looping through an array of points like this:

```
ctx.beginPath();
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(
        points[i].x - camera.position.x,
        points[i].y - camera.position.y
    );
}
ctx.stroke();
```

However I can't adapt the line to account for zoom - I can multiply all the coordinates by the zoom factor and the size appears correct, but I lose the position set by the camera, so it's not aligned to the background. Can anyone tell me how I can account for this?

I hope I've explained this well enough, I can try to upload the whole thing if anyone needs to see it in context!

Please let me know any questions, I'd really appreciate any advice or guidance.

**Edit:**

Link: http://staging.clicky.co.uk/map-scroll/ (Scroll to see the map update!)

Comment: I think a snippet that contains some working points and an example image would help a lot in answering this question. Just make sure you add the sample on here, not on some external site.

Comment: There are a lot of working parts so not sure a snippet would be easy enough to do, I've uploaded the demo so far - http://staging.clicky.co.uk/map-scroll/ I'll try and sort an example image to demonstrate too, thanks for the advice!

Comment: It looks like you need an offset depending on the zoom level. In the `lineTo` calls, for `x`, `- (zoom - 1) * 1000`, and for `y`: `- (zoom - 1) * 500` seem pretty close

Comment: @K3N Apologies, if you scroll down the page the map should pop into view. I've tried using scales and transforms but they aren't quite working as I need due to other elements on the canvas

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks - I think you're right, I need the offset - unfortunately I can't work out this formula! I tried the code you suggested and unfortunately this didn't work

Comment: Use `ctx,setTransform(zoom,0,0,zoom,-camera.position.x*zoom,-camera.position.y*zoom)` then draw the whole map (let the API clip it for you) `ctx.drawImage(map,0,0);` and then draw the path `ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y); ...` to keep the line width constant you can set it with `ctx.lineWidth = width / zoom;`

Comment: thanks @Blindman67 that got me a lot closer, the map and the path scale together now - but the camera position is incorrect and the screen isn't clearing correctly, presumably this is to do with the transform? I've updated the link in the post, thanks for the help!!

Comment: Sorry the transform position is not meant to be literal, your links dont work for me so it is just a guess, maybe something  like `-(camera.position.x + ((canvas.width  - (canvas.width  / zoom)) / 2)) * zoom` ... same for y. last two arguments of setTransform. Reset transform with `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);` to fix clearing issue.

Comment: @Blindman67 yeah I played around with the transform and it worked to a certain extent, but it caused other issues unfortunately - managed to get the offset working using this on the path coordinates: `((points[i].x - camera.position.x) - ((canvas.width - (canvas.width / zoom)) / 2)) * zoom` thanks for your help on this!